# Where can I find some artistically drawn tables demonstrating how a string of text can be stored in ASCII encoding?

Tags: resource-request

The following is an example of the type of table we wish to show to students. However, we desire to use larger fonts, more vivid highly-saturated colors (purple, golden yellow, and/or other colors), and other aesthetically pleasing features?

| T | h | e |  | c | h | i | l | d |  | s | a | t |  | o | n |  | t | h | e |  | s | w | i | n | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 84 | 104 | 101 | 32 | 99 | 104 | 105 | 108 | 100 | 32 | 115 | 97 | 116 | 32 | 111 | 110 | 32 | 116 | 104 | 101 | 32 | 115 | 119 | 105 | 110 | 103 |

However, I imagine that some students would have difficulty paying attention to a slide-show presentation having a lot of small mono-spaced white letters on a black background.

What resources for teaching are there for artistically drawn tables using rich deep colors and beautifully-to-look at fonts for students who enjoy feeling happier and more entertained?

In case you are curious, an example of code which prints out an ASCII table to the console displaying the ASCII number for each character is shown below. I can produce ugly tables, but how can we convert the ugly-looking tables into nice-looking tables?

```python
import sys
import io


def make_table(istring: str, file=sys.stdout) -> str:
    nchars = 4
    ostrm = io.StringIO()
    tops = tuple(
        ch.ljust(nchars) for ch in istring
    )

    mids = list()

    for top in tops:
        print(type(top), top)
        if "|" in top:
            mid = "|"
        else:
            mid = nchars * "-"
        mids.append(mid)

    bots = tuple(
        str(ord(ch)).ljust(nchars) for ch in istring
    )

    print("| ", end="")
    print(*tops, sep=" | ", end=" |\n", file=file)

    print("|-", end="", file=file)
    print(*mids, sep="-|-", end="-|\n", file=file)

    print("| ", end="", file=file)
    print(*bots, sep=" | ", end=" |\n", file=file)

    ostr = ostrm.getvalue()
    ostrm.close()
    return ostr


#################################################

# input string
istring = "The cat sat on a laptop"

make_table(istring)
```

---

```None
| T    | h    | e    |      | c    | h    | i    | l    | d    |      | s    | a    | t    |      | o    | n    |      | t    | h    | e    |      | s    | w    | i    | n    | g    |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
| 84   | 104  | 101  | 32   | 99   | 104  | 105  | 108  | 100  | 32   | 115  | 97   | 116  | 32   | 111  | 110  | 32   | 116  | 104  | 101  | 32   | 115  | 119  | 105  | 110  | 103  |
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the purpose. Is this going to become a poster to hang in your classroom? Or is this something you expect to do constantly?  If it's a relatively small number of artifacts to make, then that suggests different solutions.